# Get specific input value in custom helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have created helper to print out inputs the way I want to, currently method looks like this:

```
  def code_input(builder, method, is_disabled)

    builder.input method.to_sym, as: :string, label: t("activerecord.attributes.#{builder.object_name}.#{method}"),
                  input_html: { class: 'input-medium', value: is_disabled ? '*****' : builder.object.method, disabled: is_disabled }
  end
```

Problem I encountered is with input value in case when `is_disabled` is `false`. Rails prints such error:

```
wrong number of arguments(0 for 1)
```

with usage like this:

```
= code_input(f, :random_code, @code.locked)
```

But if I will do this directly in form, not by the helper like this: `f.object.random_code` I get proper value without error... Could you please explain to me what I am doing wrong I'm using formtastic and Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieved what I wanted by:

```
builder.input method.to_sym, as: :string, label: t("activerecord.attributes.#{builder.object_name}.#{method}"),
              input_html: { class: 'input-medium', value: is_disabled ? '*****' : builder.object.attributes["#{method}"], disabled: is_disabled }
```